# Error : A reference to a higher assembly or incompatible can't be added to the project

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, visual-studio-2012

i got this error  A reference to a higher assembly or incompatible can't be added to the project.When I was trying to add system.runtime.cache dll file.
I am working on window phone application there i want to fetch url from cache.
so for this i am including this library.
i am using visual studio 2012 ultimate update 4 with .net framework 4.5.51641!

Comment: The classes in System.Runtime.Caching are not supported by Windows Phone. You can't use them.

Comment: then what is the solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Reported error is due to the file being blocked by windows, as downloaded content is deemed unsafe for.The solution is to right-click on the unpacked monitor file, select Properties, and click Unblock.